# Can't compile Android and Java 8

Tags: java, android, java-8

I'm trying to compile my Android Project with Java 8. I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Library writing phase: I/O error when accessing file 'E:\AndroidStudio-workspace\AndroidStudio-workspace\AndroidJava8App\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-7e6b8fc7be3a8d7a00b87d2dcaca08e2b16b5802.jar': directory 'C:\Users\quares\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1490037714211-0' failed to be closed: Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\quares\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1490037714211-0'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception
```

Here is my some of my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "quares.androidjava8app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        incremental false
    }
}
```

Here is an Screenshot of the module:

[image: Project Settings]

And here you can see that I have Java 8 installed in my PC:
[image]

You can see, I'm compiling with version 25 of Android and I have Java 8 installed and configured for my project.

Any suggestion? I already read a lot of questions and answers but none of them help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have write permissions at the path it mentions?

Comment: Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\quares\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1490037714211-0'    That looks like a problem with writing files, not java8

Comment: clean and rebuild project, then run.

Comment: Yes, I have permission. But Android Studio, every time I compile, creates a new folder named "vfs-%" and I don't know if I have permissions there in compile time, I don't know if you can understand this (sorry for my english)

Comment: Well, Jack is now deprecated so maybe try java7 for now or java8 with retrolambda.

Comment: I can't believe that the answer I should take is "don't use java8"... It cannot be that difficult to change the environment